# Has anyone actually encountered a calendar widget that was better than just text input for DOB?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, calendar

Im learning asp.net mvc and have been investigating jquery and the like. 
As yet I havent found a calendar that is actually any good for inputting a date of birth. It often involves masses of scrolling to find the correct year! It is often easier/quicker to just type it in. 
Just wondering if anyone had found any examples of good calendars for this kind of thing or maybe could point me to some good resources if I tried to make my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a jQuery plugin called "Masked Input" - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maskedinput

Answer (score 0):

I think Jquery ui calendar is the best solution for that, you can choose year without clicking 20-30 times backwards .. you just select it from select menu , chk it out

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

You need to click on the date field to actually see it

Comment: That is a nice calendar, but I still find it easier/faster to just type it in! I think maybe I'm searching for something that doesnt exist. Im beginning to think a mask may be more appropriate.

Comment: Maybe if you told you idea how would you write this more simple than this .. someone ought to help you implement it